# How to properly send responses for ajax requests for different confirm/error situations?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, http

I am currently using the following schema: I have a form with few fields and I submit it with ajax request (using jquery form plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/ , and validate plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ )

To indicate whether this request can be successfully processed (can only create unique objects in the database) or it wasn't properly filled (for intance have to check with db ) etc etc I send the following responses using node.js :

```
    res.writeHead(204, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write("exists");
    res.end();
```

or

```
    res.writeHead(400, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end();
```

or

```
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write("Product created: " + product);
        res.end();
```

After receveiving it on client side I parse it using the following options fed into `ajaxSumit` call :

```
var form_options = {  

  success: function(restxt, ststxt, xhr){

    $("#submit_button").prop( "disabled", false);

    // console.log("status text: " + ststxt);
    if ( xhr.responseText.match(/.*notanimage.*/) ){
      showErrorAlert("Uploaded not an image file!"); 
      // clears the file input after good product submission
      $(".fileinput").fileinput('clear');
    }   
    // 204 code used here 
    // error code for product already existing in the database
    else if (ststxt == 'nocontent'){
      showErrorAlert("Product \"" + product_name + "\" already exists in the database."); 
      // clears the file input after good product submission
      $(".fileinput").fileinput('clear');
    }   
    //  
    else if(ststxt == 'success' ) { 
      showInfoAlert("Product \"" + product_name + "\" submitted successfully."); 
      // clears the file input after good product submission
      $(".fileinput").fileinput('clear');
    } else {
      showErrorAlert("Problem with submitting this form, with following error: \"" + ststxt + "\"");
    }   
  },

  error: function(){
    showErrorAlert("Problem with submitting this form.");
    $("#submit_button").prop( "disabled", false);
   }   
};
```

Is this the correct way or is there any other way I should send it from server side and parse it differently on client side ?

**EDIT**

The problem is that when I send a 409 for product already exist then I get error instead of response text in the console/browser :

```
POST https://localhost:8443/ 409 (Conflict)
```

Comment: Just by using the proper HTTP response codes you are on the right track. There is no standard after that. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AJAX (which should really be called AJAJ these days, hah), I generally prefer sending a JSON response:

```
res.writeHead(204, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
res.write(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: 'exists' });
```

Or:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
res.write(JSON.stringify({ success: true });
```

A lot of people prefer setting an `error` property when there's a failure, with the absence of that property indicating success.  I think it's better to include a `success` property because it eliminates the chance of false "successes".  Then you can just check it thusly:

```
$.ajax('/ajax/myfunc', {
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success){
          console.log('yay!');
        } else {
          console.log('boo!');
        }
    });
```

Anyway, that's the approach I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "already exists" ought to be a 409. Furthermore, "created" should be a 201 with a Location header field.